# Is there a vi editor for android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a curmudgeon developer from the former unix world who was raised on the vi editor. I can see how useful an IDE is for development (e.g. the Windows Visual platform or Eclipse) but I have always preferred to stay with the command line for my development platform because I am very proficient with vi.

I am now trying to learn the android development ecosystem with its IDE Android Studio. I must admit that I am slowly becoming a convert to using an IDE. However, the editor is still a source of frustration for me. It takes me forever just to navigate the source file much less do any complex refactoring. The genius of vi is that you never have to take your hands off the keyboard for both navigating the edit cursor and for entering code--so you become very efficient and fast. But with the Android Studio editor, I have to use the mouse to navigate to the edit position first, then return my hand back to the keyboard to entering code.

So, is there a vi editor plugin for Android Studio?

Thanks...

Comment: I think android studio gives you the flexibility to use the vim keymap with the help of [ideavim](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim) plugin this site might also be of use for you [link](https://medium.com/@ahmedrizwan/vim-ing-on-android-studio-acb8f8078101#.b0e6cxgpx)

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.

Comment: also stackexchange has a site dedicated for this purpose [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes there is, [IdeaVim](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/164-ideavim). Go to Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories and search for **IdeaVim**. Works pretty well. I would also recommend getting familiar with the [Android Studio IDE shortcuts](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) which are also handy.

Comment: I just installed that plugin...wow, this is great!!   The 2 page shortcuts is also very nice. Thanks for your help!